# How to make a hierarchical permission architecture work performantly?

Tags: design, architecture, scalability, permissions

I was going through this blog - [https://www.notion.so/blog/data-model-behind-notion](http://web.archive.org/web/20211006043229/https://www.notion.so/blog/data-model-behind-notion)

Which talks about how each page can inherit permission from parent page.

> we use an “upward pointer” — the parent attribute — for the permission system.

Take for the following hierarchy:

[image]

Here if at `Root page` 3 users have access rights, `Page 2` would inherit these permissions and the 4th user won't be able to access `Page 2 Child`.

Similarly, if at `Root Page` three users have access rights, `Page 2` permissions can be defined specifically, say 2 users have access rights. This means `Page 2 Child` would inherit `Page 2` permissions and only 2 users would be able to access `Page 2 Child`.

**Question**

While this is understandable. My question is: how are they able to scale this architecture, especially when the user base of the system gets large?

Lets say they are utilizing SQL to store their page level permissions, referencing parent page with `parent_id` foreign key.

**Scenario 1:**

When a user specifically tries to access a page, Notion traverses the parent tree through `CTE`. Stops when it finds a page which has permissions defined. Checks if the current user has permission and then shows or denies access to the page's content.

Now, this works fine and it doesn't take much time.

However, the problem arises in

**Scenario 2:**

When user triggers a search query. Notion has to first filter pages where the current user has permissions and then perform search.

Now, Notion can't possibly be doing Recursive CTE for so many pages.

---

How would they be solving this problem such that performance is not degraded?

*(Please take Notion just as one real-world example, the problem will probably occure in other comparable systems as well.)*

Comment: dont know for sure, but you could simply recalculate the page permissions when permissions change rather than calc for every search

Comment: I was also thinking the same. But then what happens in the case where there's a lot of users in the organization, multiple levels of hierarchy. Its seems like a lot of duplication.

Comment: @ShyamalParikh: the issue of having "a lot of users" is usually not handled at the "permission per page" part of the architecture. It is mitigated by the option of having user groups which get assigned the same permissions by default. Otherwise, even the manual administrative work of giving each user the right permissons becomes unwieldy.

Answer (score 2):

> When user triggers a search query. Notion has to first filter pages where the current user has permissions and then perform search.

While traversing up the tree makes sense when you have one specific page to check for rights, it doesn't really make sense if you are trying to find all the pages that a user has access to.  I think that is just another way to state the observation you have made.

If the search is fairly narrow, one approach is to simply do the search and check each result individually.  But if the search brings back a large result set, that could be problematic.

One strategy that might help is to work in the other direction instead.  Start from the root and build a white-list of all the pages the user has access to.  Then you can search only those pages.

If it's not clear why that might be faster, consider the following hypothetical page tree with nodes the user does not have access to marked with a red 'X'.

[image: page tree image created by author]

The thing to notice with that is that, as we work down the tree, once we see that the user cannot access C, we don't need to check the children of C.  We are done with that branch.  The resulting pruned tree looks like this:

[image: pruned page tree image created by author]

Now we have a structure that shows the tree as the user can see it.  When doing a search, you could search the entire space and find the intersection of those results and the nodes in the pruned tree, or you could search within the pruned tree.

This pruned tree can be cached in a user's session and would only need to be updated when the user's permissions change.  If the tree is very large, you might only prune to a certain depth and then check the permissions recursively below that depth.

It's important to note that this assumes access cannot be taken away at one level and added back at a lower level.  That is, permissions are subtractive.  IMO, that's the right way to address security and when I have dealt with systems that make it possible to access a child but not a parent, they tend to be clunky, confusing, and buggy.

This is just one possible approach and it could be refined in many ways.  I also want to note that this kind of problem is basically a simplified rules engine.  A lot of strategies are used in that space that are pretty sophisticated.  The [Rete algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rete_algorithm) is probably the most famous of these and is freely available as a published paper.  There are a number of articles freely available that discuss how it works.